# Huawei CloudEngine configuration

Tags: networking, switch

We are a medium sized company, and just updated our networking equipment. 
Due to the negligible added cost we decided to go with switches that have sfp+ ports.

As we have fiber to connect the different switches the enxt step was to buy a Huawei CE6810.

The CE6810 should "just" be a switch connecting all the other switches, firewall, servers and so on (on different vlans), no inter-vlan or other routing capability is needed.

Unfortunately, I am a bit in over my head with the configuration of the CE6810. Any pointers on where to start? What do I need to configure for it to act as a switch?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know CE switches can be used out of the box. By default all ports are in VLAN 1.

If the ports don't come up when a cable is plugged in, it's probably still in shutdown

Try:

```
sys
interface <the interface name>
undo shutdown
```

To fix that.

Otherwise all Huawei documentation can be found here: [docs](http://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/switch/cloudengine-6800-pid-7597815?category=configuration-commissioning)